# LaTeX editor that supports Hebrew

Tags: editors, hebrew, right-to-left

I am looking for a LaTeX editor that can manage Hebrew and RTL, and that is supported on OSX,
I came across many but did not find that works.
Thanks

Comment: @JosephWright I have searched the list and found not reference to Hebrew, that is why I posted that question

Comment: We're quite keen to keep any 'IDE recommendations' as far as possible in one place. Can you enlarge on why 'RTL support' does not cover Hebrew?

Comment: BTW, 'doesn't work' would probably be a motivation to edit the other question, say 'RTL: Partial (details ...)'

Comment: @JosephWright Sorry, you are right.
The editors I have tested do not display Hebrew at all, or display some of the letters

Comment: Maybe emacs for OS X will help you. see: http://emacsformacosx.com/

Comment: That sounds more likely to be because the editor font you were using didn't have Hebrew characters. For example TeXowrks for me on Windows using Courier New certainly displays Hebrew.

Comment: @JosephWright I found sharelatex.com, it is web based, but if you upload the font file, its work

Comment: @newbie Can you please try TeXworks or another standard editor, and change the editor font to any font on your system that contains the full Hebrew set? (You can check this either in a character map or in some text processor like Word or OpenOffice.) Because if the characters don't get displayed elsewhere in your system, they can hardly get displayed in a TeX editor.

Comment: @yo'I can choose from Hebrew fonts in TexStudio are there any typecast lines I need to add? as it does not work

Comment: @newbie Are you talking about using Hebrew in the editor or producing Hebrew in your output?

Comment: @JosephWright Both

Comment: @newbie The two things are entirely separate: one is about your editor, one is about your TeX set up. As it stands this question really isn't clear or clearly different from the older general one.